# Bootstrap modal issue (not able to show the second modal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

So I have two modals which are triggered depending on the button I click

The first one is trigeered like this:

```
<a id="de_details" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".show-de-banks"> </a>
```

And it is built this way

```
<div class="modal fade show-de-banks" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    bla bla
                <div class="modal-body">
                    bla bla
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    bla bla
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

An the second one is called using a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".open-dialog">Open dialog with IT-Team</button>
```

And it is built the same way:

```
<div class="modal fade open-dialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                dsfgdfg
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                sdgfsdgsd
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               sdfds
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I open the first one, I have no issue.

But when I want to open the second one, it disappear as soon as it has appeared.

I know that:

- I have to include only one js bootstrap file
- My scripts have to be at the end (for the sake of page rapidity loading)

Do I miss something?

Comment: Can you make working fiddle for your issue?

Comment: give button type as button

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers: Thanks! Was exactly the solution. Damnit!

Comment: Hahaha. I should post as answer rather than comment. better luck next time me

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers You still can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As says comment of Ubiquitous Developers [Bootstrap modal issue (not able to show the second modal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307706/bootstrap-modal-issue-not-able-to-show-the-second-modal#comment56357070_34307706) you should give button `type` as `button`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".open-dialog">Open dialog with IT-Team</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I had the same issue and found this.

In your first modal, your `div` with class `modal-header` isn’t closed - you’re missing a `</div>`.

This means that the second modal will sort of be inside the first, which causes issues.

I found the issue by looking in the Elements tab of Chrome’s F12 tools, which shows issues like this well.